# Trying to convert NSDate to Date and getting warning

Tags: ios, date, swift3, nsdate, swift4

I am getting the following warning

> Forced cast from 'NSDate?' to 'Date' only unwraps and bridges; did you
>   mean to use '!' with 'as'?

on the following line of code:

```
pickDate.date = item?.date as! Date
```

where `pickDate` is a `UIDatePicker`. The code works and if I try to follow the recommended fixes, they loop with other warnings or errors that are no better.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `item`?

Comment: item is an Entity

Comment: None of those suggestions worked - same issue.  I am able to work around the issue by grabbing the number of ms from 1970 and then creating a new Date, but feel there must be a more direct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using Swift 3.x (Xcode 8.3.3) I was able to get rid of the warning with:

```
pickDate.date = item.date! as Date
```

But this assumes "item" is not an optional anymore (on my code I can if-let it).

Answer (score 0):

```
if let model = item, item?.date != nil{

        pickDate.date = model.date

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*item is an Entity* does not provide enough info (better include the definition of the entity), but according to the message, `item?.data` is of type `NSDate?` (aka `Optional<NSData>`). You can convert `NSDate` to `Date` with `as`-casting, as well as `NSDate?` to `Date?`:

(You usually do not use `as!` or `as?` when converting between `NSDate` and `Date`.)

```
if let theDate = item?.date as Date? {
    pickDate.date = theDate
} else {
    //Generally, silently ignoring unexpected value would be a bad habit.
    print("`item?.date` is nil")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`item` maybe nil. then `item?.data` maybe nil.
try this:

```
pickDate.date = item!.date as! Date
```

or

```
pickDate.date = (item?.date)! as Date
```